# np is not defined after importing numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Why am I having this error

```py
import numpy as np
np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2304/609253908.py in 
> ----> 1 np.array([1,2,3,4])
>
> NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: The error trace and the provided code don't match.

Comment: what kind of prompt are you using?

Comment: jupiter notebook

Comment: @OFONITEX You need to run the cell where you import numpy, before any other cell

Answer (score 3):

Your error code says that `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])` is in line `1` so you are trying to use it before importing, you need to import `numpy` first, as shown in your question.

Comment: I realized that I needed to run the code from line one, each time I open it. I was only trying to run from the middle which was unable to recognize the NumPy I imported earlier in line1

Answer (score -1):

You can just go with numpy

```
import numpy
numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
```

Have you installed or updated numpy?
Try this once in your terminal.

```
>>> pip install numpy
```

Comment: This would solve a `ModuleNotFoundError` not the `NameError`.

Comment: Second one is for that.... he can try {import numpy} only.

Comment: have also updated my anaconda to the current version